# Using algolia index attributes in link_to in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algolia

I implemented **Algolia's instantsearch** on my Rails app. I use it to display a list of product as search results.

On each product there is a save button. I'd like to retrieve the id of each result to pass it along in a `link_to` tag.

For the instant search implementation I followed [Algolia's guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/instant-search/).

I created an Index called Products (on my Algolia account). It has a title and an id (+ an objectID given by Algolia).

My application.js file with the Algoli search widgets:

```
var search = instantsearch({
  // Replace with your own values
  appId: "1JJ5DY0CLA",
  apiKey: 'e24882443747d61c496efc4e17288a36', // search only API key, no ADMIN key
  indexName: 'Idea',
  urlSync: true
});


search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#search-input',
    placeholder: 'Search for growth ideas',
    poweredBy: true
  })
);

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits',
    hitsPerPage: 10,
    templates: {
      item: getTemplate('hit'),
      empty: getTemplate('no-results')
    }
  })
);


search.start();

function getTemplate(templateName) {
  return document.querySelector('#' + templateName + '-template').innerHTML;
}
```

The code inside my index.html.erb view looks like this:

```
<div id="hits"></div>

# Comment: this is the code to structure each result sent by the API
<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
    <div class="product">
       <div class="product-title">  
          <h3>{{title}}</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="product-save">
       # Comment: where I'd like to replace product_id by the result id
          <%= link_to "save",  product_path(product_id, current_user), method: :post %>
       </div>
  </div>
```

**How can I retrieve the result's id to pass it to the link_to tag ?**

Here is the result sent by Algolia (got it from the browser), don't know how to get the result variable inside the view/controller.

```
   {
      "results": 
     [
      {
       "hits":
       [
        {
          "title":"Product title1",
          "id":65,
          "objectID":"344300262"
        },
        {
          "title":"Product title2",
          "id":66,
          "objectID":"344300263"
        }
       ]
     }
   ]
```

**First tests:**

From algolia example (see above in my code) I undesrtand that I can retrieve result properties into the html like this : `{{id}}`. But I'm not sure what kind of "object" it is.

I can display the id on the page with `<%= "{{id}}" %>`. But in Ruby it is interpreted as a string `{{id}}` so I can't use it along like below:

```
<%= link_to "save",  product_path("{{id}}", current_user), method: :post %>
```

Furthermore, I saw that there is a `get_object` method I can use on my index to retrieve the whole Algolia's object like this : 
`index.get_object("objectID")`, `objectID` being an `integer`.

But as for the id, I don't know how to get the objectID of the current result displayed.

If any improvement for my question is needed, I'd be happy to make it more understandable. Just tell me.

Comment: can you show me the result variable after get result from Algolia search

Comment: I added the application.js content, and the response sent by Algolia (got it from the browser) is network tab. But I'm not sure how I can't get it from the view for instance. @Dias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dynamic helpers in your JavaScript code.
The reason for that is that the `link_to` is called only once, at server rendering time.
When the page is then served, your link to has already been converted to a `<a>` tag.

When you're using `instantsearch.js`, you're not calling the server again, the page is refreshed using only JavaScript, which means that you won't be able to use `link_to` on each render.

However, you were indeed on the good path with `"{{id}}"`. The only issue here is that the `_path` helpers are escaping the parameters, which makes sense if you're using user data to generate your path, but in this case isn't required.

You can hence unescape the generated path, like so:

```
<%= link_to "save",  CGI::unescape(product_path("{{id}}", current_user)), method: :post %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "save",  CGI::unescape(product_path("{{objectID}}", current_user)), method: :post %>
```

However, I don't guarantee that the POST method will work, you might have to rebind those `<a>` tags in a way that's unknown to me.

Comment: Thank you @Jerska. This works and so those the POST method.